# how to get username from user_id on laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

```
@foreach($productChunk as $product)
  <div class="pull-left user_id">{{ $product->user_id }}</div>
@endforeach
```

currently this is my code. it currently show the user's id that upload that product how to make it show the uploader name?

```
public function getIndex()
{
  $products = Product::all();
  return view('shop.index', compact(['products']));
}
```

and this is the code from the controller

i already made the relationship

```
//Product.php
public function user()
{
  //$this->belongsTo(User::class);
  $this->hasOne('App\User');
}


//User.php
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

public function product()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

this i the table schema for both

```
//user
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
//product
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: use `join` to get the name from user table

Comment: @AgamBanga how to use join? i really new to laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

with

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','user_id');
}
```

in Product Model.
and also use get() instead of all() in controller.

```
$products = Product::get();
```

**UPDATE:**
In Prodcut.php your user() method is not returning a relation type. You didnt notice the answer i posted earlier, see the difference between your user() method and the method i have posted earlier.  Your method need to `return` a relation type.

Replace

`public function user()
{
$this->belongsTo('App\User');
}`

with

`public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}`

in Product.php and access user name in your view using `$product->user->name`

Comment: still getting this error message : Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\shop\index.blade.php)

Comment: Replace `compact(['products'])` with `compact('products')` and check.

Comment: Please check your view tempalate carefully, there must be some problem in your view tempalte. or make new tempalte test.blade.php for testing purpose and set the template in controller `return view('test', compact('products'));` and in your view `@foreach($products as product){{$product->user->name}}@endforeach`

Comment: just tried making a new test.blade.php with just @foreach($products as product){{$product->user->name}}@endforeach and still getting the same error message when i use{{$product->name}} the error message gone but it only show the product name not the uploader's name

Comment: Post your User Model here?

Comment: added my full user model on the question

Comment: Use {{$product->user()->name}} and tell me, I am curious to find the problem here.

Comment: answer updated. you need to use `return` in user() method in product.php

Comment: OMG all this time thinking something wrong with my laravel or somthing...

Comment: i just forget to add return in front of the code. thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You must be having two models product.php and user.php. The user is linked to product using user_id field.

Then you need to add just add a relationship :

add following in product model :

```
//Product.php
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}


//User.php
public function products()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Now inside your blade you can do :

```
@foreach($productChunk as $product)
  <div class="pull-left user_id">{{ $product->user->name }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Add eager loading in controller :

```
public function getIndex()
{
  $products = Product::with('user')->get();
  return view('shop.index', compact(['products']));
}
```

Comment: i already add the relationship
but i use return $this->belongsTo('App\User)
and on the user model i use $this->hasMany('App/Product')
i just try what you said and get this error 'Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\shop\index.blade.php)'

Comment: what is the name of function you have written in product model for belongsTo ?

Comment: Also make sure you have return the relationship in both models relationships. If you forget to return it will throw above error.

Comment: i add what i wrote on those model at the question.. and at your answer on mistake..

Comment: Can you try making $this->belongsTo('App\User'); in product user function and do $product->user->name in blade? And also check if field is not name in users table, retrieve appropriate field

Comment: Hey also eager load the users in query like : $products = Product::with('user')->get();

Comment: i already try making $this->belongsTo('App\User'); in product user function and do $product->user->name in blade, and i already check the field name and still get the same error. on my earlier project when i start learning laravel i use that method and it work i dont know why this time it wont work

Comment: What is your table schema. I am curious to find the issue now :)

Comment: just added the schema on the question

Comment: and again i add it on your answer by mistake

Comment: after adding eager loding i getting this error: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Comment: I think i found the workaround : try this return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id'); and try again. Try with and without eager load. This time it should work

Comment: well i tried that and still getting the error.. is my laravel corrupted or what.. can i email you my code instead?